# Why not connect to all (huge amount of) nodes?

Tags: network, peers, relay, block-propagation-time, latency

If you mine, a good network propagation time is important in case of mining-forks. I read that bitcoin only connects to 8 nodes. I would connect to many nodes as I can support to minimize my block propagation time?